# libpgiod vs wiringPI code/configuration

Tags: wiringpi, libgpiod

I have an RPI, setup with wiringPi and some code I wrote to read a quadrature encoder. It works just fine, I can read the pins, using a wiringPiISR mechanism (the ISRs get executed on the rising as well the falling edges of the encoder signals/channels

In a different setup I am trying to re-write "the whole" thing using libgpiod. I found an example or two that show how to test for an event,  a gpio pin being raised or lowered. However, I don't seem to be able to get them to work.

I am wondering,  does wiringPi configure the pins in someway when you call it's init functions?

Does anyone have a pointer to a working example? (I tried an input 'demo' as well, didn't seem to work either, but figured the signal might change too fast or so.)

thanks,

Ron

Answer (score 1):

I am not impressed with libgpiod.  Frankly it seems to be a retrograde step compared to sysfs.

Here is some partial code which calls up other not included code.  It should give you enough of an idea to get your own code working.

```c
#include <stdint.h>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <poll.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "lgHdl.h"
#include "lgDbg.h"
#include "lgErr.h"

#include "lgGPIO.h"

#define LG_GPIO_MAGIC 1623920569

#define LG_MODE_UNUSED       0
#define LG_MODE_GPIO         1
#define LG_MODE_EVENT        2

#define LG_GPIO_MAX_EVENTS_PER_READ 16

typedef struct lgGPIOState_s
{
   int mode;
   int flags;
   int group_size;
   int fd;
   uint32_t offset;
   uint32_t *offsets;
   uint8_t *values;
} lgGPIOState_t;

typedef struct lgChip_s
{
   uint32_t magic;
   char name[LG_GPIO_NAME_LEN];
   char label[LG_GPIO_LABEL_LEN];
   uint32_t lines;
   int fd;
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIOState;
   char defaultClaimUser[LG_GPIO_USER_LEN];
   uint32_t claimNextExtraFlags;
} lgChip_t, *lgChip;

void _lgGpioCloseChip(GPIOHandle_t *h)
{
   int i;
   lgChip chip;

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return;

   chip->magic = 0;

   for (i=0; i<chip->lines; i++)
   {
      if (chip->GPIOState[i].mode != LG_MODE_UNUSED)
      {
          /* release GPIO */
          LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "release GPIO: %d mode %d (%d of %d)",
             i,
             chip->GPIOState[i].mode,
             chip->GPIOState[i].offset+1,
             chip->GPIOState[i].group_size);

          if (chip->GPIOState[i].offset == 0)
          {
              LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "close fd: %d", chip->GPIOState[i].fd);

              close(chip->GPIOState[i].fd);

              LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "free offsets: *%p, values: *%p",
                 (void*)chip->GPIOState[i].offsets,
                 (void*)chip->GPIOState[i].values);

              free(chip->GPIOState[i].offsets);
              free(chip->GPIOState[i].values);
          }
      }
   }

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "free GPIOState: *%p", (void*)chip->GPIOState);

   free(chip->GPIOState);

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "close chip fd: %d", chip->fd);

   close(chip->fd);

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "free chip: *%p", (void*)chip);

   free(chip);
}

int lgGpioOpenChip(char *device)
{
   int fd;
   int handle;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;

   lgChip chip;
   struct gpiochip_info info;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "device=%s", device);

   fd = open(device, 0);

   if (fd < 0) return LG_CANNOT_OPEN_CHIP;

   if (ioctl(fd, GPIO_GET_CHIPINFO_IOCTL, &info))
   {
      close(fd);
      return  LG_NOT_A_GPIOCHIP;
   }

   chip = calloc(1, sizeof(lgChip_t));

   if (chip == NULL)
   {
      close(fd);
      return LG_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
   }

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "alloc chip: *%p", (void*)chip);

   chip->GPIOState = calloc(info.lines, sizeof(lgGPIOState_t));

   if (chip->GPIOState == NULL)
   {
      free(chip);
      close(fd);
      return LG_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
   }

   handle = lgHdlAlloc(LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO, sizeof(GPIOHandle_t), _lgGpioCloseChip);

   if (handle >= 0)
   {
      h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);
      h->chip = chip;
   }
   else
   {
      free(chip);
      close(fd);
      return LG_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
   }

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "alloc GPIOState: *%p", (void*)chip->GPIOState);

   chip->magic = LG_GPIO_MAGIC;

   strncpy(chip->name,  info.name,  sizeof(chip->name));
   strncpy(chip->label, info.label, sizeof(chip->label));

   chip->lines = info.lines;

   chip->fd = fd;

   strncpy(chip->defaultClaimUser, "lg", sizeof(chip->defaultClaimUser));

   chip->claimNextExtraFlags = 0;

   return handle;
}

int lgGpioCloseChip(int handle)
{
   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d", handle);

   return lgHdlFree(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);
}

int lgGpioGetLineInfo(int handle, unsigned gpio, lgLine_t *line)
{
   int status;
   struct gpioline_info linfo;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d gpio=%d line=*%p",
      handle, gpio, (void*)line);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (gpio >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   linfo.line_offset = gpio;

   status = ioctl(chip->fd, GPIO_GET_LINEINFO_IOCTL, &linfo);

   if (status == 0)
   {
      line->offset = linfo.line_offset;
      line->flags = linfo.flags;
      strncpy(line->name, linfo.name, sizeof(line->name));
      strncpy(line->user, linfo.consumer, sizeof(line->user));
   }
   else status = LG_BAD_LINEINFO_IOCTL;

   return status;
}

int lgGpioHandleRequest(int handle, struct gpiohandle_request *req)
{
   int i, gpio;
   int status;
   uint32_t *offsets;
   uint8_t *values;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d req=*%p", handle, (void*)req);

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "request %d with flags %d: GPIO=[%s]",
      req->lines, req->flags, lgDbgInt2Str(req->lines, (int *)req->lineoffsets));

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   status = ioctl(chip->fd, GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, req);

   if (status == 0)
   {
      offsets = calloc(req->lines, sizeof(uint32_t));
      values = calloc(GPIOHANDLES_MAX, sizeof(uint8_t));

      if ((offsets == NULL) || (values == NULL))
      {
         free(offsets);
         free(values);
         close(req->fd);
         return LG_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;
      }

      LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "alloc offsets: *%p, values: *%p",
         (void*)offsets, (void*)values);

      for (i=0; i<req->lines; i++)
      {
         gpio = req->lineoffsets[i];

         chip->GPIOState[gpio].mode = LG_MODE_GPIO;
         chip->GPIOState[gpio].flags = req->flags;
         chip->GPIOState[gpio].group_size = req->lines;
         chip->GPIOState[gpio].fd = req->fd;

         chip->GPIOState[gpio].offset = i;

         chip->GPIOState[gpio].offsets = offsets;
         chip->GPIOState[gpio].values = values;

         offsets[i] = gpio;
         values[i] = req->default_values[i];
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if (errno == EBUSY) status = LG_GPIO_BUSY;
      else
      {
         fprintf(stderr, "*** error %d (%s) ***\n", errno, strerror(errno));
         status = LG_UNEXPECTED_ERROR;
      }
   }
   return status;
}

int lgGpioRelease(int handle, unsigned id)
{
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIO;
   int i, g, status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d id=%d", handle, id);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (id >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   GPIO = &chip->GPIOState[id];

   switch (GPIO->mode)
   {
      case LG_MODE_UNUSED:
         return LG_OKAY;

      case LG_MODE_GPIO:

         LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "release GPIO: %d (mode %d)", id, GPIO->mode);

         for (i=0; i<GPIO->group_size; i++)
         {
            g = GPIO->offsets[i];
            LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "set unused: %d", g);
            chip->GPIOState[g].mode = LG_MODE_UNUSED;
         }

         LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "close fd: %d", GPIO->fd);

         close(GPIO->fd);

         LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALLOC, "free offsets: *%p, values: *%p",
            (void*)GPIO->offsets, (void*)GPIO->values);

         free(GPIO->offsets);
         free(GPIO->values);

         return LG_OKAY;

      case LG_MODE_EVENT:
         close(GPIO->fd);
         GPIO->mode = LG_MODE_UNUSED;

         return LG_OKAY;
   }

   return LG_BAD_RELEASE_OBJECT;
}

int lgGpioSetClaimUserLabel(int handle, char *user)
{
   int status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   strncpy(chip->defaultClaimUser, user, sizeof(chip->defaultClaimUser)-1);

   return LG_ERR_NONE;
}

int lgGpioSetClaimExtraFlags(int handle, uint32_t flags)
{
   int status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   chip->claimNextExtraFlags = flags;

   return LG_ERR_NONE;
}

int lgGpioClaim(
   int      handle,
   unsigned flags,
   unsigned size,
   unsigned *gpios,
   unsigned *values)
{
   int i;
   uint32_t addedFlags;
   int status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   struct gpiohandle_request req;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d size=%d gpios=[%s] values=[%s] flags=%x",
      handle, size, lgDbgInt2Str(size, (int*)gpios),
      lgDbgInt2Str(size, (int*)values), flags);

   /*
   Any flags may be set by a direct call to lgClaim.

   Only LG_GPIO_SET_ACTIVE_LOW, LG_GPIO_SET_OPEN_DRAIN, LG_GPIO_SET_OPEN_SOURCE
   may be added as flags by lgGpioSetNextClaimAddFlags.
   */

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   addedFlags = chip->claimNextExtraFlags &
      (LG_GPIO_SET_ACTIVE_LOW|LG_GPIO_SET_OPEN_DRAIN|LG_GPIO_SET_OPEN_SOURCE);

   chip->claimNextExtraFlags = 0;

   if (size && (size <= GPIOHANDLES_MAX))
   {    
      for (i=0; i<size; i++)
      {
         req.lineoffsets[i] = gpios[i];

         if (values != NULL) req.default_values[i] = values[i];
         else                req.default_values[i] = 0;
      }

      req.flags = flags | addedFlags;

      strncpy(req.consumer_label, chip->defaultClaimUser, sizeof(req.consumer_label));
      req.lines = size;

      return lgGpioHandleRequest(handle, &req);
   }
   else return LG_BAD_GROUP_SIZE;
}


int lgGpioClaimInput(int handle, unsigned gpio)
{
   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d gpio=%d", handle, gpio);

   return lgGpioClaim(handle, GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_INPUT, 1, &gpio, NULL);
}

int lgGpioClaimOutput(int handle, unsigned gpio, unsigned value)
{
   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d gpio=%d value=%d",
      handle, gpio, value);

   return lgGpioClaim(handle, GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT, 1, &gpio, &value);
}

int lgGpioClaimInputGroup(int handle, unsigned size, unsigned *gpios)
{
   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d size=%d gpios=[%s]",
      handle, size, lgDbgInt2Str(size, (int*)gpios));

   return lgGpioClaim(handle, GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_INPUT, size, gpios, NULL);
}

int lgGpioClaimOutputGroup(
   int handle, unsigned size, unsigned *gpios, unsigned *values)
{
   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d size=%d gpios=[%s] values=[%s]",
      handle, size, lgDbgInt2Str(size, (int*)gpios),
      lgDbgInt2Str(size, (int*)values));

   return lgGpioClaim(handle, GPIOHANDLE_REQUEST_OUTPUT, size, gpios, values);
}

int lgGpioClaimEvent(int handle, unsigned gpio, unsigned eFlags)
{
   uint32_t addedFlags;
   int status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   struct gpioevent_request req;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d gpio=%d eFlags=%x",
      handle, gpio, eFlags);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   addedFlags = chip->claimNextExtraFlags;
   chip->claimNextExtraFlags = 0;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (gpio >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   req.lineoffset = gpio;
   req.handleflags = LG_GPIO_SET_INPUT | addedFlags;
   req.eventflags = eFlags;
   strncpy(req.consumer_label, chip->defaultClaimUser, sizeof(req.consumer_label));

   status = ioctl(chip->fd, GPIO_GET_LINEEVENT_IOCTL, &req);

   if (status == 0)
   {
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].mode = LG_MODE_EVENT;
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].flags = addedFlags;
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].group_size = 1;
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].fd = req.fd;
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].offset = 0;
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].offsets = NULL;
      chip->GPIOState[gpio].values = NULL;
      return LG_OKAY;
   }
   else
      return LG_BAD_EVENT_REQUEST;
}

int lgGpioRead(int handle, unsigned gpio)
{
   int status;
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIO;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d gpio=%d", handle, gpio);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (gpio >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   GPIO = &chip->GPIOState[gpio];

   if (GPIO->mode == LG_MODE_UNUSED) return LG_GPIO_NOT_ALLOCATED;

   status = ioctl(GPIO->fd, GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, GPIO->values);

   if (status == 0)
      return (GPIO->values[GPIO->offset]);
   else
      return LG_BAD_READ;
}

int lgGpioWrite(int handle, unsigned gpio, unsigned value)
{
   int status;
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIO;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d gpio=%d value=%d",
      handle, gpio, value);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (gpio >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   GPIO = &chip->GPIOState[gpio];

   if (GPIO->mode == LG_MODE_UNUSED) return LG_GPIO_NOT_ALLOCATED;

   GPIO->values[GPIO->offset]=value;

   status = ioctl(GPIO->fd, GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, GPIO->values);

   if (status == 0)
      return 0;
   else
      return LG_BAD_WRITE;
}

int lgGpioReadGroup(int handle, unsigned group, unsigned *values)
{
   int i;
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIO;
   int status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d group=%d values=*%p",
      handle, group, (void*)values);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (group >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   GPIO = &chip->GPIOState[group];

   if (GPIO->mode == LG_MODE_UNUSED) return LG_GPIO_NOT_ALLOCATED;

   status = ioctl(GPIO->fd, GPIOHANDLE_GET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, GPIO->values);

   if (status == 0)
   {
      for (i=0; i<GPIO->group_size; i++) values[i] = GPIO->values[i];

      return LG_OKAY;
   }
   else
      return LG_BAD_READ;
}

int lgGpioWriteGroup(int handle, unsigned group, unsigned *values)
{
   int status;
   int i;
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIO;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO, "handle=%d group=%d values=*%p",
      handle, group, (void*)values);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (group >= chip->lines) return LG_BAD_GPIO_NUMBER;

   GPIO = &chip->GPIOState[group];

   if (GPIO->mode == LG_MODE_UNUSED) return LG_GPIO_NOT_ALLOCATED;

   for (i=0; i<GPIO->group_size; i++) GPIO->values[i]=values[i];

   status = ioctl(GPIO->fd, GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, GPIO->values);

   if (status == 0)
      return LG_OKAY;
   else
      return LG_BAD_WRITE;
}

int lgGpioFetchEvents(
   int handle,
   unsigned num_gpio,
   unsigned *gpios,
   unsigned max_event,
   lgEvent_t *events,
   unsigned timeout)
{
   int i, e;
   int retval;
   unsigned count;
   unsigned how_many;
   int bytes;

   struct gpioevent_data evDat[LG_GPIO_MAX_EVENTS_PER_READ];
   struct pollfd *pfd;
   lgGPIOState_t *GPIO;
   int status;
   GPIOHandle_t *h;
   lgChip chip;

   LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_GPIO,
      "handle=%d num_gpio=%d gpios=[%s] max_event=%d events=*%p timeout=%d",
      handle, num_gpio, lgDbgInt2Str(num_gpio, (int*)gpios),
      max_event, (void*)events, timeout);

   status = lgHdlCheckType(handle, LG_HDL_TYPE_GPIO);

   if (status < 0) return status;

   h = lgHdlGetObj(handle);

   chip = h->chip;

   if ((chip == NULL) || (chip->magic != LG_GPIO_MAGIC)) return LG_CHIP_NOT_OPEN;

   if (num_gpio > chip->lines) return LG_TOO_MANY_GPIOS;

   pfd = calloc(num_gpio, sizeof(struct pollfd));

   if (pfd == NULL) return LG_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY;

   for (i=0; i<num_gpio; i++)
   {
      GPIO = &chip->GPIOState[gpios[i]];

      if (GPIO->mode == LG_MODE_UNUSED)
      {
         free(pfd);
         return LG_GPIO_NOT_ALLOCATED;
      }

      pfd[i].fd = GPIO->fd;
      pfd[i].events = POLLIN|POLLPRI;
   }

   count = 0;

   while (count < max_event)
   {
      retval = poll(pfd, num_gpio, timeout);

      if (retval < 0)
      {
         free(pfd);
         if (count == 0) count = LG_POLL_FAILED;
         return count;
      }
      else if (retval == 0)
      {
         break;
      }

      for (i=0; i<num_gpio; i++)
      {
         if (pfd[i].revents)
         {
            how_many = max_event - count;

            if (how_many > LG_GPIO_MAX_EVENTS_PER_READ)
               how_many = LG_GPIO_MAX_EVENTS_PER_READ;

            bytes = read(pfd[i].fd, &evDat, how_many * sizeof(evDat[0]));

            e = 0;

            while (bytes >= sizeof(evDat[0]))
            {
               events[count].timestamp = evDat[e].timestamp;
               events[count].edge = evDat[e].id;
               events[count].gpio = gpios[i];
               if (++count >= max_event) break;
               bytes -= sizeof(evDat[0]);
               e++;
            }

            if (bytes)
            {
               LG_DBG(LG_DEBUG_ALWAYS, "### bytes left=%d (%s)\n",
                  bytes, strerror(errno));
               free(pfd);
               if (count == 0) count = LG_POLL_FAILED;
               return count;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   free(pfd);

   return count;
}
```

Comment: Hello Joan, well, I am not really thrilled yet either, but sysfs has been deprecated, it is (or going to be) part of Linux, the documentation and examples are lacking.. So I definitly agree. (I am glad making a living doesn't depend on it for me.)  Thank you for the code example!!..  -- Ron

Answer (score 0):

Wiringpi does far more than setup GPIO pins.

If you want to implement ISR using libgpiod  you will have to write your own code.

You would be better to explore PIGPIO. It is not as well documented as Wiringpi but far more capable.

Comment: Well, I kind of figured that, I know how to write an ISR, that is not the issue. What I am trying to figure out is why that libgpiod function doesn't seem to be triggered. I prefer not to use something outside of "standard" libraries. libpgiod is going to be a part of linux, so that is a cleaner more preferable way of doing it.  So maybe I need to rephrase the question into,  what is it one needs to do so that a function like "gpiod_line_event_wait" (or similar functions, actually do and need. I am aware that I'd need to write my own code, I am just looking for some pointers on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

btw:   this is a code "example" I saw ..  it looks very simple (as working with libgpiod is said to be, but doesn't work).  There is also a regular input source file, which also doesn't work.  There is a pin out put file, that I did get to work.

here's is an event example I found a few days back:

```c
#include <gpiod.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#ifndef CONSUMER
#define CONSUMER        "Consumer"
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *chipname = "gpiochip0";
    unsigned int line_num = 27;     // GPIO Pin #27
    struct timespec ts = { 1, 0 };
    struct gpiod_line_event event;
    struct gpiod_chip *chip;
    struct gpiod_line *line;
    int i, ret;


    chip = gpiod_chip_open_by_name(chipname);
    if (!chip) {
        perror("Open chip failed\n");
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("%s: opened.\n", chipname);

    line = gpiod_chip_get_line(chip, line_num);
    if (!line) {
        perror("Get line failed\n");
        gpiod_chip_close(chip);
        return -2;
    }
    else
        printf("line number: %d\n", line_num);


    ret = gpiod_line_request_rising_edge_events(line, CONSUMER);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("Request event notification failed\n");
        gpiod_line_release(line);
        gpiod_chip_close(chip);
        return -3;
    }

    /* Notify event up to 20 times */
    i = 0;
    while (i <= 20) {
        ret = gpiod_line_event_wait(line, &ts);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("Wait event notification failed\n");
            gpiod_line_release(line);
            gpiod_chip_close(chip);
            return -4;
        }
        else if (ret == 0) {
            printf("Wait event notification on line #%u timeout\n", line_num);
            continue;
        }

        ret = gpiod_line_event_read(line, &event);
        printf("Get event notification on line #%u %d times\n", line_num, i);
        if (ret < 0) {
            perror("Read last event notification failed\n");
            gpiod_line_release(line);
            gpiod_chip_close(chip);
            return -5;
        }
        sleep(1);

        i++;
    }

    gpiod_line_release(line);
    gpiod_chip_close(chip);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.